# Use Postgres to parse stringified JSON object

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I've been using Postgres to store JSON objects as strings, and now I want to utilize PG's built-in `json` and `jsonb` types to store the objects more efficiently.

Basically, I want to parse the stringified JSON and put it in a `json` column from within PG, without having to resort to reading all the values into Python and parsing them there.

Ideally, my migration should look like this:

```sql
UPDATE table_name SET json_column=parse_json(string_column);
```

I looked at [Postgres's JSON functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html), and there doesn't seem to be a method of doing this, even though it seems pretty trivial. For the record, my JSON objects are just one-dimensional arrays of strings.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: `json` and `jsonb` don't *store* the objects more efficiently. If all you do is store and retrieve JSON values, you might as well stick with `text`. The JSON types are interesting if you want the database to do something with the data, like process them (`jsonb`) or check their integrity (`json`).

Comment: Actually, `jsonb` **does** store the objects more efficiently, since it is storing it in binary representation instead of string representation. For big data sets this can be a critical gain in storage space, which also affects index size and more. Secondly, storing JSON as text is as stupid as storing integers as text. Even if there is no practical need for it, data clarity should always be enforced, and as you said, having the database checking the integrity is never a bad idea.

Comment: I agree that conversion to `json` could hardly be a loss. But I am curious if you actually tested that `jsonb` needs less space than `text`. `text` is stored compressed by default if it exceeds a certain length (TOAST). And `INSERT` and `SELECT` will take slightly longer because the value has to be parsed or unparsed.

Comment: Obviously, it very much depends on what type of data you are storing. As my JSON objects are a list of strings, the storage cost could be comparable to TOASTed text, but for a complex data type with many large numbers, storing binary representations will provide a huge gain. And furthermore, if you've ever dealt with large data sets that might change over a period of time, you've probably learnt that choosing the right data representation type is imperative to a clean DB. Your comments are unconstructive, since my question was not "should I?", but rather "how can I?".

Comment: I was referring to the OPs remark: *I want to utilize PG's built-in `json` and `jsonb` types to store the objects more efficiently*. But it's no use having a theoretical discussion about this here.

Comment: I *am* the OP. And as you said, there is no use having a theoretical discussion here. If you want a practical discussion, here's one: I need to be able to filter and index based on the array's **length**, and I think we need no discussion to prove that `jsonb` and even `json` is much more *efficient* for storing arrays with this use case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need for a `parse_json` column, just change the type of the column:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN json_column TYPE json USING json_column::json;
```

Note that if you plan on doing a lot of JSON operations on these values (i.e. extracting elements from objects, modifying objects etc) it's better to use `jsonb`. `json` should only be used for storing JSON data. Also, as Laurenz Albe points out, if you don't need to do any JSON operations on these values and you are not interested in the validation that postgresql can do on them (e.g. because you trust that the source always provides valid JSON), then using `text` is a perfectly valid option (or `bytea`).

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt and informative response! I think a more general answer about parsing JSON objects would be better for future references. That is, the most important thing I learnt from your answer is that casting to JSON types (`::json` or `::jsonb`) is the standard way of parsing JSON strings in PG. Too bad there doesn't seem to be any documentation about this feature.